# Callback with "this"

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to call a callback function with a "this" pointer in the following way:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe("map_metadata", 1, &Obstacle::metaDataCallback, this);
```

The Callback function is:

```
//Get the occupancy grid metadata.
void Obstacle::metaDataCallback(const nav_msgs::MapMetaData::ConstPtr& msg) {       
        this->width = msg->width;
        this->height = msg->height;
        this->resolution = msg->resolution;
}
```

When I try to print the width, height and resolution of "this" after the callback has returned, the values are always 0 (as when initialized). However, I know they should be 288, 288 and 0.1 respectively. Why aren't the parameters properly stored in "this"? How can I make it so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66154/callback-with-%22this%22/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check a few things that could be wrong:

- Is your callback actually being called?

  - *add a print statement in the callback to make sure*
  - *check `rqt_graph` to see if your node is actually subscribed to the topic*
- Does your "Obstacle" object go out of scope?
- Does the subscriber object (`sub`) go out-of-scope?
- Did you remember to call `ros::spin()`?

Here is some example code that works for me.  See below for usage.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nav_msgs/MapMetaData.h>

class Obstacle
{
public:
  ros::Subscriber sub;
  unsigned int width, height;
  float resolution;

  Obstacle() : width(0), height(0), resolution(0)
  {
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    sub = node.subscribe("map_metadata", 1, &Obstacle::metaDataCallback, this);
  }

  void metaDataCallback(const nav_msgs::MapMetaData::ConstPtr &msg) {
    this->width = msg->width;
    this->height = msg->height;
    this->resolution = msg->resolution;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "subTest");

  Obstacle obs;

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    ROS_INFO("width: %d, height: %d, resolution: %g",
             obs.width, obs.height, obs.resolution);
    ros::spinOnce();
    sleep(2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Build this node and run it.  It should start printing out the current member-variable states (all-zeros).  Then, publish your message.  It should start printing the new values, once the messages are received.  For testing, I manually published a message:

```
$ rostopic pub "map_metadata" nav_msgs/MapMetaData "{width: 1, height: 2, resolution: 3.14159}"
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-28**:
Thanks so much for your answer! I'm new to programming Callbacks and in C++, so my code is different and not well structured. It is not working despite the fact that I did use rosSpin, that the Callback is being called, etc. I don't know what the problem is, so I'll use your code as a basis instead!

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-06-28**:
I would encourage you to not just drop your old code.  Try to compare what works and doesn't work to find out where the problem is.  That's the only way you'll learn!

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-28**:
I got it to work based on your code. Thanks again!

Well it's too late now. One thing that was different is that I was calling "spin" from within a method of obstacle instead of doing that in main. Moreover I had no while loop. Then maybe I was printing the values before actually setting them.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-08-17**:
Hi Zayin. I am wondering, if the "width" and "height" in MapMetaData is referring to the width and height of the entire map, or the individual cell in the entire map?

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-08-26**:
I supposed you had a look at this: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html.
They're parameters for the entire map, while the cell size is determined by its resolution afaik.